# Should we post faulty audits on MSO?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

Welp, came across [yet another bad audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/8800451), and the question instantly became *should I even bother reporting this*?

To my understanding they're chosen semi-randomly; can the moderators even do anything about them? Should I bother putting time into reporting them on meta? I realize I wasn't banned from this particular audit, but if it means helping out the next guy I'd be willing to post about them.

Comment: To stop the audits from affecting any other users, you can vote down and vote to close if applicable. This will (I believe) remove it from the audit pool.

Comment: I don't remember WHERE it was said, but as Tiny Giant says, you can vote down and VTC. Audits are not "semi-random", they are taken from UNEQUIVOCAL posts. If a post NEVER gets any "negative" action (Downvote, close vote, too many edits, etc), it's considered "good" by the system. If you see such an audit, take the reverse action (if there is no downvote and the audit expects you to upvote, go to the question and downvote it, it should take it off of the audits)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Should you bother? Depends on what your goal is.

There's better logic for picking these audits in the works, thanks in large part to the folks who've reported these over the years. So if your goal is to see improvements to the audit-selection procedure, please do report them - but also try to identify signals that the system could've picked up on when deciding whether to use the post.

And of course, you're always free to raise a [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question) for discussion here on meta if you think there's a problem with it that's been overlooked.

But if neither of these applies and you just didn't like the audit for some reason, then posting it here isn't of much use.

Comment: First case is definitely what I'm after. Will continue reporting them :)

Comment: @Qix - Also, several of the questionable close vote audit cases pointed out on Meta have exposed some *interesting* voting patterns around the questions and users involved. Moderators have been able to act on some of that information to clean a few things up. If a particular audit case seems really odd, it can sometimes be handy to ask how it ended up that way.

Comment: Aww shucks... Its good to know you care ;P